# Which of the following values can the function $y = \tan(x)$ take on if $\frac{\pi}{2} \lt x \lt \frac{3\pi}{4}$ holds?

Tags: trigonometry

I have this mathematical problem, but can't seem to figure out reasoning behind this:

*Which of the following values can the function $y = \tan(x)$ take on if $\frac{\pi}{2} \lt x \lt \frac{3\pi}{4}$ holds?*

List of options to choose:

- $-8$
- $-\frac{1}{8}$
- $0$
- $\frac{1}{8}$
- $8$

I knew that on this interval of unit circle, the value of $\tan(x)$ will be negative, since value of $\cos(x)$ is negative and $\sin(x)$ is positive here. So either $-8$ or $-\frac{1}{8}$ has to be the right answer. I choose $-\frac{1}{8}$, but the correct answer was $-8$. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are in only half of the second quadrant,  the half that is closer to the $y$ axis.  This means in that 45 degree arc,   the $x$ coordinate will be smaller than the $y$ coordinate in absolute value, and since $\tan(\theta)=\frac y x$ where $(x,y)$ is the point on the unit circle associated with $\theta$,  in this area your numerator will be greater than your denominator, which means the magnitude will be greater than 1.

Comment: You mean numerator greater than denominator?

Comment: Yes, since sin(x) is always greater than cos(x) on this interval in absolute values, then numerator (sin) has to be bigger than denumerator (cos) in absolute value. Therefore -1/8 doesn't satisfy this. Makes perfect sense, thank you.

Comment: @coffeemath Woops, right.  Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plot (in blue) of the tangent function with red lines at your candidate values:

[image]

Which candidate values can your tangent function take??

Comment: *I* know what this means, but I imagine it's not very clear to the OP what is going on in this diagram...